# What does the inherit keyword in CSS do?

Tags: css

Can somebody please explain what the `inherit` keyword means in CSS and how it works?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It will use the same value as the same property its parent has.

```css
body {
   margin: 234px;
}
h1 {
   margin: inherit; /* this equals 234px in this instance */
}
```

```html
<body>
   <h1></h1>
</body>
```

If there are multiple instances of `<h1>` in the file, it will take the margin of its parent, so 234px is not always the value it will have. For example:

```html
<body>
    <h2></h2>
    <div>
        <h2></h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
}
div {
    margin: 30px;
}
h2 {
    margin: inherit; /* 20px if parent is <body>; 30px if parent is <div> */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, `inherit` doesn't do anything unless you're using it to override another style rule, otherwise it's just reinforcing the default behavior.  Note that the overriding rule should be higher specificity or be below the rule that it overrides.

```css
.pink {
background-color:pink;

}
.green {
background-color:lightgreen;
}

.override {
background-color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="pink">
  <p class="green">I'm classed "green", and I am green.</p>
  <p class="green override">I'm also classed "green" but `inherit` overrides this and causes me to inherit pink from my parent.</p>
</div>
```