# What does inherit mean in CSS?

Tags: css

I often use `background: inherit;`. Like this, many other CSS properties accept inherit as a value.

But what does `inherit` mean? How does it work?

Comment: Inherit it from parent class

Comment: You should really try googling first. Here's a good link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/inherit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`inherit` means simply that the style will be inherited from the element's parent. For example:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhMdt/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="blue">
    <div class="inherit">I also have a blue background!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blue { background: blue; }
.inherit { background: inherit; }
```

Using `inherit` on `background` will normally not do you much good however, and normally produce the same as the default of a transparent background would. The above example adds nothing really, it puts a blue background on top of a blue background, the main purpose of `inherit` is for use in certain default values like with `color` and `font-size`.

Answer (score 4):

It does what inheritance does in general .. that is inherit the property of the parent element

say we have following html

```
<div>
  <h1>text<h1>
 </div>
```

and we have css like

```
 div
  {
    padding : "10px"
 }
 h1
 {
   padding : inherit //10px
 }

since h1 is child of div so will use the value of padding property for div
```

also see this thread [What does the inherit keyword in CSS do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002514/what-does-the-inherit-keyword-in-css-do)

Comment: I got stuck on treehouse, this question helps, thanks btw