# How to set css child element but not apply for inside element of child element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have simple code as below. **I want set css red color for text `aaa`**. You can see i have set css for `span`
I thinked that only text `aaa` will set red color, however css applied for both `aaa` and `bbb`. I don't understand it. Please explain it for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <style>
          #test > span {
              color:red
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="test">
          <span>aaa
              <span>bbb</span>
          </span>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, `color` simply gets _inherited_. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564650/what-does-inherit-mean-in-css

Comment: Color is inherited, you can either override it or `color: unset;`

Comment: hi CBroe, but i just only set css for first `span`. I still don't understand why `second span` auto inherited color from `first span`?

Comment: apply color to the `body` and you will also have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css!

```css
#test > span >span{
    color:black;
}

#test > span{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="test">
          <span>aaa
              <span>bbb</span>
          </span>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <style>
          #test > span {
              color:red
          }
         #test > span > span {
              color: #000;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="test">
          <span>aaa
              <span>bbb</span>
          </span>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```